# Mouse events in Kinetic JS 3.6

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

```
this.prototype.bounding = new Kinetic.Shape(function () {
    var context = this.getContext();
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fill();
},"PerspectiveCar");
this.prototype.bounding.vx = 0;
this.prototype.bounding.vy = 0;
this.prototype.bounding.x = positionX;
this.prototype.bounding.y = positionY;    
this.prototype.bounding.on("mousedown", function () {
        alert('Hi');
});
```

Hi,
I'm using KineticJS 3.6 version.
Mouse events does not work here.
i don't know the reason.
can u help me.

Thanks Vijay

Answer (score 0):

It also doesn't work for "click" ?

```
this.prototype.bounding.on("click", function () {
        alert('Hi');
});
```